# DISTINCT ON two fields MYSQL + rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a model Message which consists of :title,:description,:sender_id,:receiver_id. So Records of Message Model may

1. Message.first
   (id:1, title: "Sample1", description: "Test1", sender_id: 1, receiver_id: 2)
2. Message.second
   (id:1, title: "Sample2", description: "Test2", sender_id: 3, receiver_id: 4)
3. Message.second
   (id:1, title: "Sample3", description: "Test2", sender_id: 3, receiver_id: 4)

I want a query which gives distinct record based on sender_id and receiver_id

In Postgres
Message.select("DISTINCT ON (sender_id, receiver_id) *")  works

But MYSQL2 giving error please help

Edit

Work around from me

```
messages = [] 
messages << Message.all.to_a.uniq{|m| m.sender_id} 
messages << Message.all.to_a.uniq{|m| m.receiver_id} 
@messages = messages.flatten.uniq
```

Comment: Can you open `rails db` and try the query `select m1.* from messages AS m1 JOIN messages m2 ON m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id 
AND m1.receiver_id = m2.receiver_id 
GROUP BY m1.sender_id, co1.receiver_id
HAVING m1.created_at = MAX(co2.created_at)` and let me know what you got.

Comment: `distinct on` is specific to Postgres, so you cannot use it in MySQL.  You should post your entire query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  `Message.select("DISTINCT ON (sender_id, receiver_id) *")`  is a query in Rails will work with Postgresql. The OP knows it.. probably looking for a similar one for MySql

Comment: Thanks Anup for understanding my doubt and Explaining to @GordonLinoff. Unfortunately the query which you provided is not working. Giving an error ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'co1.receiver_id' in 'group statement'

Comment: @GouravNaik when solved you could give an answer here, it could help others like me.

Comment: i made a temporary solution messages = [], messages <<  Message.all.to_a.uniq{|m| m.sender_id}   messages <<  Message.all.to_a.uniq{|m| m.receiver_id} and finally @messages = messages.flatten.uniq

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `GROUP BY` should do just fine:

```
Message.group(:sender_id, :receiver_id)
```

Comment: This is not what i wanted, Your query will return by making an group of ids, I wanted whole message to return based on the sender and receiver id uniqness

Comment: `GROUP BY` won't return a group of ids. It will return one (random record's) id. You will be able to use `message` objects returned with that query as usual.